# Homology group 0 of wedge sum

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

This might have been asked but I couldn't find it anywhere. Is the homology group $H_{0}(X)$ of a wedge sum $X = \vee_{\alpha}X_{\alpha}$ equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ if $X$ is path-connected, or is it $\oplus_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}_{\alpha}$? From one side, $H_{0}(X)$ should be equal to $\mathbb{Z}$ because $X$ is path-connected. From the other side, we have $H_{n}(X) = \oplus_{\alpha}H_{n}(X_{\alpha})$ and each $X_{\alpha}$ is path-connected, so it should equal $\oplus_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}_{\alpha}$.

Can someone clarify my mistake in thinking here.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula $H_{n}(X) = \oplus_{\alpha}H_{n}(X_{\alpha})$ is not correct as stated. It would become correct if homology $H_n$ were replaced with reduced homology $\tilde H_n$.

Comment: So to confirm, $\hat{H}_{n}(X) = \oplus_{\alpha}\hat{H}_{n}(X_{\alpha})$ and since $H_{0} = \hat{H}_{0}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ it would imply all $\hat{H}_{0}(X_{\alpha}) = \{0\}$? Then $H_{0}(X) = \hat{H}_{0}(X)\oplus \mathbb{Z} = \oplus_{\alpha}\hat{H}_{0}(X_{\alpha}) \oplus \mathbb{Z} = 0\oplus \mathbb{Z}  = \mathbb{Z}$.